# RubyMine IDE Cannot Find Spec Files in Spec directory

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I have loaded a Ruby project into RubyMine, that has it's spec files located in a `spec` directory, as usual. Right-clicking and selecting 'run' on any single spec file correctly runs it. Right-clicking and selecting 'run all' on the `specs` directory causes every test to fail with the following message:

> Fail to load: /Users/nathaniel/repos/close-web/spec/compositions/analysis/analysis_data_spec.rb:1
>         Exception message: cannot load such file -- spec_helper

Inside the launch configuration, the 'Tests folder' seems to be set correctly:

```
/Users/nathaniel/repos/close-web/spec
```

And the working directory as well:

```
/Users/nathaniel/repos/close-web
```

The Ruby arguments are set like this:

```
-e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Itest
```

(There is some indication on the RubyMine website that `-Itest` is required.) Under the Bundler tab 'Run the script in the context of the bundle' is checked as well. I'm unclear what else RubyMine might need to be able to recursively find and execute the tests. Running them from the command line works fine:

```
~repos/closeweb $ bundle exec rspec spec
... (all the tests running)

Finished in 6 minutes 27 seconds (files took 13.39 seconds to load)
1054 examples, 0 failures, 108 pending
```

What configuration is wrong here that all the tests won't run?

Comment: Given that your folder is called `spec`, not `test`, I presume that you need to `-Ispec`, not `-Itest`.

Comment: @TomLord That was it! Thank you. I didn't realize that was the meaning of that flag. If you want to put an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your folder is called `spec`, not `test`, you need to `-Ispec`, not `-Itest`.

In other words, your RubyMine arguments should be:

```
-e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -Ispec
```

From the [ruby man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby):

```
-I directory   Used to tell Ruby where to load the library scripts.
               Directory path will be added to the load-path variable ($:)
```